# Delphi FireMonkey Indy TIdHttp how to abort?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin update and Indy's TIdHttp component.
I usually abort a connection using the following code:

```
procedure TMyThread.OnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: int64);
begin
    if abort then (asender as tidhttp).Disconnect;
end;
```

This works fine in a VCL application, also in a FireMonkey application as long the platform is Windows. When I use this code with MacOS as target, it close my application instantly without error message or anything displayed.

So my question here is what am I doing wrong, and how can I abort a connection when the platform is MacOS?

Comment: FireMonkey has been plagued with exception handling issues on OSX for years. There are numerous reports in QualityCentral related to runtime error 231. AFAIK, a root cause was never found, but has been acknowledged as a problem.

Comment: use modern THTTPClient instead of Indy

Comment: @Zam - I have to stick with Indy, I cant change the huge amount of functions to something else for now.

Comment: So I can test this properly, what is the idHTTP control doing at the time you want to cancel? (Connecting, downloading, etc).

Comment: THttpClient has also issues. I have some sites when accessing them via THttpClient, I get after a while an error that the sire redirected too much or something like that. Using indy. it did not even redirect once for the same urls.

Comment: Looks almost like nobody use Indy with firemonkey and have a working abort code... so many firemonkey issues... like its only half baked.

Comment: @Softtouch Indy works just fine with FireMonkey in general, this issue is specific to OSX and Delphi's poor exception handling on OSX.  Unfortunately, Indy makes pretty heavy use of exceptions and that can't be changed.  Granted, FireMonkey support is an after-thought, since Indy was already a well-established and mature library before FireMonkey came along, but I think I got most of the issues out (ARC handling, etc) by now (though it seems a lot of that work will [no longer be an issue in 10.4](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-october-Delphi-ARC-directions.html))

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 10.4? Your link point to your 10.3 blog article, and 10.3 still has the same issues related to OSX and firemonkey.

Comment: @Softtouch yes, Delphi 10.4. I was referring to the "The New Plan: Phasing Out ARC" section of that blog article.

Answer (score 3):

Rather then call `Disconnect()` directly and rip the socket connection away from `TIdHTTP`, I would raise an exception instead, like calling `SysUtils.Abort()`, and let `TIdHTTP` or the calling thread close the socket after the request has been fully aborted.

```
procedure TMyThread.OnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: int64);
begin
  if Self.Abort then SysUtils.Abort;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    ...
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In only works on a PC, but when running on a Mac, the app close completely, and paserver shows runtime error 231. I tried to debug it, but nothing is executed after the abort line anymore, and also the idhttp.get does not return in that case.

Comment: As of today, I could not find any solution to properly abort indy when running on MAC OSX.  This issue renders indy completely useless, because user have no way to abort a connection.

Comment: @Softtouch then you need to contact Embarcadero for support. This is a Delphi issue, not an Indy issue. Indy relies pretty heavily on exceptions  so if exception handling is broken on OSX then Embarcadero needs to fix that on their end.

Comment: I already reported it at Embarcadero. I was hoping somebody has a temporary fix or idea about it, because my project is now on a complete halt, due to the fact that user are not able to abort the connection.

Comment: See [Mac OS X Exception Handling](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/mac-os-x-exception-handling-5628) and [OS X Application Development: Exception Handling](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/OS_X_Application_Development#Exception_Handling) in Embarcadero's documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting links. But how will that help me with the indy issues? It looks like there is no working solution. Indy fail, net http client cannot set proxies on OSX and only use the system proxy, httpsend does not work on osx, ics does not work on osx. With other words, its all half baked only and programming for OSX using delphi is a waste of time.

Comment: Heck, indy is just a headache! Using the connect timeout, cause crashes, disconnect does not work, and thats now with 10.2 Tokyo. Does anybody know a WORKING internet component suite for firemonkey which will work on MAC and allow to use proxies???

Comment: @Softtouch again, this is not an Indy issue, it is a Delphi issue. Exception handling simply does not work correctly on OSX. Take it up with Embarcadero. Things like Connect timeout, and disconnecting mid-work, use exceptions.

Comment: I did report it, and nothing of course. And thats why I was asking for another http component which will work under OSX.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
procedure TMyThread.OnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: int64);
begin
  try  
    if abort then (asender as tidhttp).Disconnect;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help. On the Mac, it will cause an expected exception, but will still not abort the connection...

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    try
     ...
    except
      on E:Exception do ...//do not re-raise it.
    end
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Try catching the thread exception.